# Fetching Dynamic Inputs data in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I'm trying to create a html table that looks like an excel sheet. Users can click an add new entry button add a new row to the table in which every `<td>` displays of an `input`. Its looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHW9S.png).

here is what I'm doing:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let row of getRowCount()">
  <td><input type="text" name="date" class="form-control" /></td>
  <td><input type="number" name="start_time" class="form-control" /></td>
  <td><input type="number" name="finish_time" class="form-control" /></td>
  <td width="150px">
    <select name="users" class="form-control">
      <!-- this will be from db -->
      <option value="" selected>Alex</option>
      <option value="">John</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td><input type="number" name="duration" class="form-control" /></td>
</tr>
```

I want to send all of this inputs data back to the parent component when user clicks done. But, I'm having trouble understanding, how to parse these dynamically created inputs. One idea is to create an array of objects and each object will hold fields like name, start_time etc.

But, How can I fetch this data from these inputs. Any suggestions would really be helpful.

Comment: Have you go through Angular dynamic forms? https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

Comment: How about using ngModel within each td and fetching each set of values into an array of objects